# Can't find DLL entry point

Tags: c++, vba, dll, entry-point

I have been trying to call a DLL function in my VBA project but I keep getting this error message:

`Run-time error '453': Can't find DLL entry point "CheckStatus" in "Power.dll"`

Here is the definition for the DLL in the C++ file:

`#define CLASS_DECLSPEC   extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport)`

`CLASS_DECLSPEC int __stdcall CheckStatus();`

And here is how I'm trying to declare it and call it in VBA:

```
Public Declare Function CheckStatus Lib "Power.DLL" () As Long

Dim test As Long
test = CheckStatus
```

And then when I run it received the aforementioned error message.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165080%28v=office.10%29.aspx) MSDN article, I would try this method of declaring the function:

```
Public Declare Function CheckStatus Lib "Power.DLL" Alias "_CheckStatus@0" () As Long
```

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with name mangling (even with `extern "C"`).
Look at what export is really in the DLL, a guess would be either `_CheckStatus` or `_CheckStatus@0`.
To force the name to be as-is, make a `.def` file in your project with the content:

```
EXPORTS
    CheckStatus=CheckStatus
```

Comment: Yeah the name of the function is `_CheckStatus@0`. Do I modify the declare statement or the calling statement? Both?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to VB and VBA. Can you create a `.DEF` file in VBA or do you need VB6? Because we do not have VB6.

Comment: I'm trying to search but cannot figure out how to create a `.DEF` file. Can I do this with VBA? I don't have access to the source for the DLL. I don't mind the name mangling if it means just calling the functions by cryptic names as long as it works.

Comment: @JohnSmith: the def file goes in the c++ project.

Comment: Is there any way to call the functions without access to the C++ project?

Comment: @JohnSmith: you can use alias, like `LIb "something.dll" Alias "name@0"`